# How can I automatically silence my computer at night?

Tags: scripting, audio

I would like to set my Ubuntu computer such that I can't hear any audio between 9:59pm and 8:00am. How can I do that?

Comment: setup a cron job to mute your master audio channel at 21.59 and unmute it at 08.00?

Comment: Turn off the computer between the designated hours.  Will save on your electric bill too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found this method on AskUbuntu that shows using a crontab entry along with `amixer` to mute/unmute the sound. It's titled: [How do I automatically mute/unmute sound during a certain time period (e.g. night)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235340/how-do-i-automatically-mute-unmute-sound-during-a-certain-time-period-e-g-nigh).

#### General steps

1. Create a crontab entry

   ```
   $ crontab -e
   ```
2. Add entries to crontab

   ```
   59 21 * * * amixer set Master mute
   00 08 * * * amixer set Master unmute
   ```
3. Save
   (if you are using ViM, then e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are asking this because you want it to be done automatically rather than having somebody tell you "Just turn the volume down when you go to bed".

Go to a shell prompt and use "crontab -e" and add two events along this lines of this:

```
0 21 * * * /usr/sbin/amixer -D pulse  sset Master,0 0%
0 8  * * * /usr/sbin/amixer -D pulse  sset Master,0 100%
```

The first will run a 9pm every day and the second at 8am every day.

The device used may be different on your computer, depending on the hadrware, so run amixer by itself first to see what you have.

E.g.

```
bytor@VaporTrails[22:21:41]~$ amixer -D pulse
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
...
```